# jQuery - running the same function on list of buttons

Tags: jquery

I have a list of 50 buttons that need to call the same function, which gets the button's unique value:

HTML

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".query").on("click", function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('value'); // $(this) refers to button that was clicked
    alert(id);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group">
  <button value="alabama" class="query">Alabama</button>
  <button value="alaska" class="query">Alabama</button>
  <button value="arizona" class="query">Arizona</button>
</div>
```

But pressing a button doesn't cause it to pop up an alert, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Change the buttons id to be the name. Then access the id attribute in Jquery.

Comment: Your code appears to be working. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: It works on jsfiddle and chrome, but not on the browser I'm using for some reason. I wish I can delete this now thanks for the help

Comment: dodgy browser?  press f12 and have a look at the console - are there any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited your code and it's working fine.

Please keep in mind that, [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) works only on the elements which are present in the DOM at the time of page load as you are binding elements at the time when DOM is ready.

So if you are adding button dynamically then you should use [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/), But as `.live()` is deprecated so you should use [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) or below code method of binding present and the future elements.

```
// jQuery 1.4.3+
$( elements ).delegate( selector, events, data, handler );
// jQuery 1.7+
$( elements ).on( events, selector, data, handler );
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".query").on("click", function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('value'); // $(this) refers to button that was clicked
        alert(id);
        })
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group">
        <button value="alabama" class="query">Alabama</button>
        <button value="alaska" class="query">Alabama</button>
        <button value="arizona" class="query">Arizona</button>
```

Comment: `.live()` has been deprecated for more than 75 years now. Use event delegation in case of dynamically added elements: `$(document).on('click, '.query', function() { ... })`

Comment: Can you please tell me why you have downvoted it? So that I can improve my answers in future.

`To Whosoever downvoted it`

Comment: I didn't, but will now because this is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Thanks @connexo, I have edited my answer. I had been using `.live()` till now. Thanks.

Comment: No problem buddy, You are independent to do so. Thanks.  @connexo

Comment: And I added answer because I don't have enough reputation to add comments. I just wanted to help him. As a result, my reputation is more ruined now. No problem. I learned something worth to it.

Comment: I recommend earning some reputation by giving proper answers then. Undone my -1 in recognition of your intention and limitations.

Comment: @ShivamSharma, `delegate()` is also deprecated.

Comment: Thank you @connexo

Comment: Thanks @JamesHill , I read it. It's deprecated 2 years before. I'll take care of it too.